# Need help to convert "find k-th smallest of two sorted arrays" into "kth-largest"

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I have some C++ code that finds k-th smallest item of two sorted arrays in O(log(m * n)) time. I know it's not the most optimal solution, and I know it is possible to solve it in O(log(min(m, n))), however I'm not interested in it yet.

I want to convert this function to make it return k-th largest item instead, and I struggle to make it work. It must be a matter of careful tweaking some comparisons here and there, but I could not make it work. Can I have some help here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

// speed: O(log( m * n) ))
// space: O(1)
int solveKthSmallest(vector<int>& A, vector<int>& B, int k, int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd)
{
    std::cout << "solveKthSmallest: (" << k << "): [" << aStart << "," << aEnd << "] [" << bStart << "," << bEnd << "]\n";

    // If the segment of on array is empty, it means we have passed all
    // its element, just return the corresponding element in the other array.
    if (aEnd < aStart) {
        return B[k - aStart];
    }
    if (bEnd < bStart) {
        return A[k - bStart];
    }

    // Get the middle indexes and middle values of A and B.
    int aIndex = (aStart + aEnd) / 2;
    int bIndex = (bStart + bEnd) / 2;
    int aValue = A[aIndex];
    int bValue = B[bIndex];

    // If 'k' is in the right half of A + B, remove the smaller left half.
    if (aIndex + bIndex < k) { 
        if (aValue > bValue) {
            return solveKthSmallest(A, B, k, aStart, aEnd, bIndex + 1, bEnd);
        } else {
            return solveKthSmallest(A, B, k, aIndex + 1, aEnd, bStart, bEnd);
        }
    } 
    // Otherwise, remove the larger right half.
    else { 
        if (aValue > bValue) {
            return solveKthSmallest(A, B, k, aStart, aIndex - 1, bStart, bEnd);
        } else {
            return solveKthSmallest(A, B, k, aStart, aEnd, bStart, bIndex - 1);       
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

double findKthSmallest(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2, int kIdx) {
    return solveKthSmallest(nums1, nums2, kIdx, 0, nums1.size() - 1, 0, nums2.size() - 1);
}

void t1()
{
    vector nums1{ 1, 4, 5, 8, 9 }; 
    vector nums2{ 2, 3, 6, 7 };

/*
    A: [ 1, 4, 5, 8, 9  ] : An = 5
    B: [ 2, 3, 6, 7 ]     : Bn = 4

    Al        Am        Ar
      [ 1, 4, 5, 8, 9  ]         

    Bl     Bm       Br
      [ 2, 3, 6, 7 ]

    Al <= Am <= Bm <= (Ar & Br)
*/

    cout << findKthSmallest(nums1, nums2, 3) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    t1();

    return 0;
}
```

I know it is possible to work around it and call it like this:

```
double findKthLargest(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2, int kIdx) {
    int revIdx = nums1.size() + nums2.size() - 1 - kIdx;
    cout << "revIdx: " << revIdx << "\n";

    return solveKthSmallest(nums1, nums2, revIdx, 0, nums1.size() - 1, 0, nums2.size() - 1);
}
```

But what I want is to modify solveKthSmallest method (copy it and rename solveKthLargest) to so that it can retain its original algorithm but be called like this

```
return solveKthLargest(nums1, nums2, kIdx, 0, nums1.size() - 1, 0, nums2.size() - 1);
```

Comment: *"I want to convert this function to make it return k-th largest item instead, and I struggle to make it work."* -- This sounds like a text replacement of `<` with `>`, done with a critical eye (not all `<` necessarily should to be replaced). What sort of error did this give you?

Comment: "Could not make it work" is not a good enough description of the issue. Please provide a [mcve] with the expected and actual input. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugg to see why you are not getting the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call a "work around" is the most sensible way to do it. Reason is that `k` is now a reversed position, which you still need to translate to an index. And to do that you need to involve the size of both arrays. As `solveKthGreatest` will be a recursive function, you'll need to do that conversion on *each* recursive call. It would look like this:

```
int solveKthGreatest(vector<int>& A, vector<int>& B, int kIdx, int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd)
// Use of different parameter name                   ^^^^^^^^
{
    std::cout << "solveKthGreatest: (" << kIdx << "): [" << aStart << "," << aEnd << "] [" << bStart << "," << bEnd << "]\n";
    // Calculate the index from the reversed index we got as argument
    int k = A.size() + B.size() - 1 - kIdx;
    if (aEnd < aStart) {
        return B[k - aStart];
    }
    if (bEnd < bStart) {
        return A[k - bStart];
    }

    int aIndex = (aStart + aEnd) / 2;
    int bIndex = (bStart + bEnd) / 2;
    int aValue = A[aIndex];
    int bValue = B[bIndex];

    if (aIndex + bIndex < k) { 
        if (aValue > bValue) {
            return solveKthGreatest(A, B, kIdx, aStart, aEnd, bIndex + 1, bEnd);
//                                        ^^^^
        } else {
            return solveKthGreatest(A, B, kIdx, aIndex + 1, aEnd, bStart, bEnd);
        }
    } 
    else { 
        if (aValue > bValue) {
            return solveKthGreatest(A, B, kIdx, aStart, aIndex - 1, bStart, bEnd);
        } else {
            return solveKthGreatest(A, B, kIdx, aStart, aEnd, bStart, bIndex - 1);       
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The only changes are:

- The name of the argument changed from `k` to `kIdx`
- Definition of a local variable `k`
- The recursive calls pass `kIdx` as argument instead of `k`

You could move the calculation of `k` to the expressions where `k` is used (there are three of them), and so omit the variable `k`, but that looks even less elegant.

Unless you have other constraints, I would still stick to the solution you presented yourself.